# GAN model with different optimization functions

Tags: deep-learning, optimization, autoencoder, gan, generative-models

Building `GAN` model contains the following steps:

1. Build `generator` model, and choose `optimization` function for this model.
2. Build `discriminator` model, and choose `optimization` function for this model.
3. Build `GAN` network:

   3.1 Build model with the architecture of the first 2 models (`generator`, `discriminator`)

   3.2 Choose `optimization` function for this network

There are some issues I'm not sure about them:

1. It seems that `generator` model and `discriminator` model can have different `optimization` functions, am I right ?

- What is the purpose of this choice ?
- Is it realistic and data scientist use this ?

2. It  seems  that  we can choose  different `optimization` function for `GAN` model which is not the same as `generator` or `discriminator` models.

- Am I right ?
- What is the purpose of this choice ?
- Is it realistic and data scientist use this ?

Comment: Could you please quote a reference if it is a specialized GAN architecture? In the case of a simple GAN, I believe there would be only two losses _i.e. one for Discriminator and one for the GAN_.

Comment: If it is a simple GAN, why would we use 2 different loss functions ?

Comment: Ok. Please clarify one more thing. Do you mean two-loss functions _i.e. MSE and cross_entropy_  Or you mean two-phased training? Since the loss functions are the same so I believe the second question seems more relevant.

Comment: I mean 2 different loss function (i.e MSE and adam)

Comment: Adam is not a _loss function_. It is the _optimizer_. It would be better if you add the reference code link.

Comment: you are right. I updated from loss to optimization function

Comment: I don't think it is True in a general sense. Please share the reference  link/book/code. Would be easy to understand and answer with that